# How can I ensure an http request comes from specific user?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, security

I am writing an additional service for a website, which utilises the existing login behaviour, while requiring some additional signup details from the user. The new service runs in a different subdomain.

The user will be able to create resources on my data web app, which must be saved against that user's data collection.

I expect that this user identifier will be passed to the webapp in the body of the http request.  However, I am concerned that a malicious attack could rewrite the user name in the body to make requests appear as if from another user.

What can I do to make this safer?  (And does this count as a CSRF attack?)

The new service is written in Java, with Spring 3.

Comment: when you say Spring 3 do you mean Spring Security also?

Comment: No, all current security is handled by the main app, and we don't have any access to it, except to retrieve the current user guid and name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never ensure an http request comes from a specific user, you can only attempt to validate a user and a request. Usually this is done by creating a ticket during the login or authentication process, then requiring that ticket on subsequent requests. You can then match the ticket with the user and accept that as valid. The ticket expires after a period of inactivity, requiring the user to login again.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought about doing - if there was no magic possible.

Comment: Adding an Absolute Session time, in addition to an Inactivity time, will make it more secure. For example, 20 minutes inactivity OR 4 hours absolute and re-authentication and a new ticket are generated.

Comment: While you cannot trust IP address and referrer host info (both can be spoofed), if you get a different IP/referrer than expected you can (and should) require re-authorization because something is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the requests through the same security stack that the main website uses if at all possible.

If it isn't possible, I would use Spring Security to handle the authentication. I'm not sure what plugins already exist for Spring Security for authenticating service requests like that, but you could always require that a cookie be used for the session, and then it's just a matter of the client dealing with the authentication steps.

So, you could use a "normal" form logon, or you could put together a token request setup, but that is much more involved.